# Need help constructing my Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am implementing a list class for a project and am really confused on how to set up my makefile. I did all my coding in the Xcode IDE and it compiles perfectly there but I need to make sure I can compile my program on unix. I used c++11 features in my code and was under the impression I was writing the flag correctly in my makefile -std=c++11 but it's not being recognized. I have my List.hpp, List.h, test_list.cpp all in the same directory as my make file as well. Do I need to write something different in my makefile since my implementation of my list class is a hpp file and not a cpp file?

This is the error I am getting word for word:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -o proj2.x test_list.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [proj2.x] Error 1
```

Could someone help explain where I am going wrong with my makefile? If there is anything else I should post to assist someone in answering my question do let me know.

Here is what I have:

```
C=g++
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

proj2.x: test_list.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -g -o proj2.x test_list.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o *.x
```

Comment: Does your gcc version support that flag, or do you have to provide `-std=c++0x` instead?

Comment: How can I check if my gcc version supports this flag? I tried -std=c++0x but that didn't work

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile does not have any problems with it. The issue is that your version of gcc is tool old to have the `-std=c++11` option! That didn't get added until 4.7. gcc 4.4 doesn't even have that much [C++11 support](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) anyway, so this seems like a great opportunity to upgrade.

The latest release is [5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/), or if you want to maintain ABI compatibility, [4.9.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/). 4.8.1 I believe was the first version to be feature complete, so no reason to start lower than there.

Comment: This was helpful I will upgrade then. I appreciate it!